# TypeError: Neo4j does not support PackStream parameters of type int64

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo, recommendation-engine

I am writing a simple recommender system by using neo4j Graph Database. I use py2neo lib, this is my program:

```
...
for m,row in movie.iterrows() :
    tx.run(statement1, {"A": row.loc['id'], "B": row.loc['title'], "C": row.loc['IMDb url']})

    is_genre = row.iloc[-19:]==1
    related_genres = genre[is_genre].axes[0].values

    for g in related_genres :
        tx.run(statement2, {"A": row.loc['id'], "B": row.loc['title'], "C": row.loc['IMDb url'], "D": g})
    if m%100==0 : tx.process()
tx.commit()
```

Then, an error occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\quy.lv\Desktop\He_thong_goi_y\He_thong_goi_y_phim.py", line 48, in <module>
    tx.run(statement2, {"A": row.loc['id'], "B": row.loc['title'], "C": row.loc['IMDb url'], "D": g})
  ...
TypeError: Neo4j does not support PackStream parameters of type int64
```

It seems to happen in the line: 
`tx.run(statement2, {"A": row.loc['id'], "B": row.loc['title'], "C": row.loc['IMDb url'], "D": g})`

Can anyone help me fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding int() to convert np.int64 type to int type such as:

```
tx.run(statement1, {"A": int(row.loc['id']), "B": row.loc['title'], "C": row.loc['IMDb url']})
```